# I have a student table there was some of data . I use only two field for login email id and password. Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

[image]
Route

```
Route::get('/','StudentController@studentlogin')->name('index');
```

Here is login request.. and I can successfully login

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $email=$request->email;
    $password=$request->password;
    $students=Student::where('email','=',$email)
    ->where('password','=',$password)
    ->first();

    if($students){
        // Session::put('email',$request->email);
        // Session::put('id',$request->id);

        return redirect()->route('student.dashboard');
    }
    else{
        Session()->flash('success','Invalid Email & and password');
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
}
```

Here is no problem. But Reactive a single row of data which row I used to login (email and password). How can I get this? Only single-row data on the different page.. please help me.

I want to reactive of a single column data on this pages this  page route is

```
Route::get('/sudent/view','StudentController@studentview')->name('student.view');
```

Comment: I don't understand `But Reactive a single collum of data which collum i used to login`. Please explain in detail

Comment: it should means that want to all data from this  row .. example.. i use admin@admin.com and password admin@admin.com when i am login then i get this row data .. in information pages

Answer (score 0):

First of all please **DO NOT** store passwords as plain text in the database. This is a massive security issue. You should be hashing the password first and storing that hash. Then when the user tries to login, you should hash the password they provided and compare against what is already in the database. For more information check the [Authentication documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication).

The way you should implement what I think you want with the Student view is to use [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-parameters). These allow you to have the ID of the user in the route and access that in your controller.

Your route should look this:

```
Route::get('/student/{student}', 'StudentController@studentview')->name('student.view');
```

the **{student}** part of the route should be replaced with an actual ID of the student you want to view when accessing the site.

Then your controller, the view method should look like this:

```
public function studentview(Student $student) {
    // Your code here
}
```

The method takes advantage of Laravel's Service Container to automatically inject the correct student based on the ID in the route parameter. This is explained further [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-model-binding)